# Problems getting the Jakarta connector to work with IIS

Tags: iis, tomcat

Why isn't my Jakarta connector setup for Tomcat working?

It seems like almost every time we are to install Jakarta Connector to run with IIS, there are unexplained troubles. Im posting this question just to get answers to different problems collected at one place.

Comment: Won't add answer cos Brimstedt is a good one. I had a LOT of problems with jakarta, because the docs are rubber. Now, I usually configure 2 each week with no problem. Advices: DONT touch registry. Never. Configure all in .properties. Make sure that Net 2.0 is installed and running. Make sure that you allow EACH isapi.dll in the Extension menu. I usually make 2 folders: www-web and web-connector and put dll and properties on second, and maintenance page on the firt. Read the documentation many times to undertand it, because is a really bad documentation. Luck!

Answer (score 1):

- Check the logs

Find the jakarta iis module logs to diagnose the problem. If the logs are not created, the problem is getting the module to load/run or its a misconfiguration.

If the logs are created, enable debugging level output in the jakarta module setting to help you diagnose the problem.

- IIS Setup

Check that the Jakarta filter module has a green upwards pointing arrow, not a red one. If it is red, check the application event log. If nothing is in the log, send a request to the web service that should be forwarded to tomcat (i.e. the (sub)domain of the website running in tomcat)

- Event log

The application Event log in windows can give you useful hints. A good collection of possible causes are here: http://blogs.msdn.com/david.wang/archive/2005/06/21/HOWTO_Diagnose_and_Fix_Common_ISAPI_Filter_Installation_Failures.aspx

The 'data' part of the message (for example 02 00 00 00) is an error code, which can come from windows OR the dll. In case it comes from windows you can use: "NET HELPMSG 2" to get the message in clear text.

If you get the 02 (file not found) or 05 (Access denied) you can try to use Sysinternal's FileMon utility to figure out exactly which file it is failing to load. It could be the dll, or one of its config files (or possible something completely different :-).

- Config files

In some setup instructions it says that you can put the jakarta settings in the registry. **This did not work for me!** 
I had to put them in a file instead!

If registry settings are not working and you are sure you spelled the keys correctly and put them int the correct place - and they are readable by the IIS users - try using a config file instead.

Of course - make sure your config files are correct. The Jakarta logs will help you with this.